# How to arrange four figures in a 2 X 2 grid in LaTeX?

Tags: floats

For a journal article that I am writing, I need to put four plots in a single figure in a 2 X 2 grid with captions for each figure. How to do it? Any help is highly appreciated.. Thanks..

Comment: Please tell us more about the structure of the figures. E.g., are they four subfigures, each with a caption and with an overall caption, or are they four individual figures and associated captions. Please also tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: You can use the `subfig` package with command `\subfloat[subcaption]{}` in a `figure*` environment supposing you have a two-column article.

Comment: Yes, correct. I like to prepare a figure with an overall caption consisting of 4 subfigures arranged in a 2 X 2 grid and I like to have each subfigure having its own caption.. A 4-D system I like to plot and projections onto four 2 dimensional planes like (x, y), (x, z), (y, z), (x, w) planes.. The answer received here works perfectly for my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `subfig` package with command `\subfloat[subcaption]{}` in a figure* environment supposing you have a two-column article.

Here I use `\includegraphcs`, but you can also `\input` a Ti*k*Z figure.

Consider the following MWE:

```tex
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfig}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \section{Introduction}
    \lipsum[1-5]
    \begin{figure*}[t!]
        \subfloat[A Cap]{%
            \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-a}%
            \label{subfig:a}%
        }\hfill
        \subfloat[B Cap]{%
            \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image-b}%
            \label{subfig:b}%
        }\\
        \subfloat[C Cap]{%
            \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \label{subfig:c}%
        }\hfill
        \subfloat[D Cap]{%
            \includegraphics[width=.48\linewidth]{example-image}%
            \label{subfig:d}%
        }
        \caption{Caption}
        \label{fig:fig}
    \end{figure*}
    \section{Conclusion}
    \lipsum[6-20]
\end{document}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks for kind help !! Best wishes, Sundar

Comment: Does `\subfloat` automatically readjust the input images to a common size?

Comment: @saQuist No, it does not. The `\subfloat` command works like a wrapper over the original image, so the size of the image should be set with the option in `\includegraphics`.